Using dynamic arrays in OpenMP loop gives different results of the serial
The following function compute the square matrix arrayrmsd, but the result is different depending on the value of export OMP_NUM_THREADS=x (x = number of cores used). Differences are low but significant and cannot be due to numerical approximations (IMHO).
The arrayrmsd is a matrix of nmol x nmol elements. Note: arrayrmsd[i,j] == arrayrmsd[i x nmol + j].
What I wanted to do is to run in parallel the optimize() function, which is in the internal for loop. This function compares the molecular structure mol1c with all the structures contained in arrcar[] and store the numerical difference in arrayrmsd[i,j].
Because the first parameter of the optimize() function is modified, I need to have an array of mol_omp[0..numthr] that should be used exclusively by the assigned thread.
The idea here is to run in parallel only the for loop that contains the optimize() function (the code after #pragma omp for).
Before the #pragma omp parallel I initialized the corresponding mol_omp[i] for all the threads.
I am new to OpenMP, and I cannot understand where my code is wrong:
    void create_rmsd_matrix(double *arrayrmsd, int nmol, CRISTALLO *mol1c, CRISTALLO *arrcar, double tolerance) {
      int i, k, numthr;
      double resol;
      CRISTALLO *mol_omp;

      for (i=0; i < nmol; i++) for (k=0; k < nmol; k++) arrayrmsd[i * nmol + k] = (double) 0.0;
      numthr = omp_get_max_threads();
      mol_omp = (CRISTALLO *) malloc(sizeof(*mol_omp) * numthr);
      for (i=0; i < numthr; i++) {
        (mol_omp + i)->natoms = arrcar->natoms;
        (mol_omp + i)->num_symbols = arrcar->num_symbols;
        initmol(mol_omp + i);
      }
    #pragma omp parallel private(i,k) shared(nmol,arrayrmsd,arrcar,tolerance)
    {
      int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp for private(i,k) schedule(static,1)
      for (i=0; i < nmol; i++) {
        molcpy(mol_omp + tid, arrcar + i);
        printf("Processing struc N. %d by thread n %d\n", i+1, tid);
        for (k = i + 1; k < nmol; k++) {
          arrayrmsd[i * nmol + k] = optimize(mol_omp + tid, arrcar + k, tolerance);
          printf("[ %5d , %5d ] = %.12lf     (thread %d)\n", i+1, k+1, arrayrmsd[i * nmol + k], tid);
        }
      }
    }
      for (i=0; i < numthr; i++) {
        free((mol_omp + i)->list_atomi);
        free((mol_omp + i)->num_atomi);
        free((mol_omp + i)->x);
        free((mol_omp + i)->y);
        free((mol_omp + i)->z);
      }
    }

There is a similar question, but I cannot understand whether it can be applied to my case. Here the main difference is that I have a dynamic array that every thread must use independently.
Probably the problem reside in data race, but I cannot figure out where, because all the element of the arrayrmsd can be computed independently.
Where I am wrong? Thank you!
I tried several #pragma omp parallel options, but honestly I'm lacking of knowledge in OpenMP.
The serial code and the parallel code run with OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 gave identical results, but if OMP_NUM_THREADS>1 the content of the arrayrmsd matrix differs.
Edit:
arrcar array is not modified.
molcpy(mol1, mol2) simply copy the molecular structure mol2 into mol1:
    void molcpy(CRISTALLO *mol1, CRISTALLO *mol2) {
      int i;
    
      mol1->natoms = mol2->natoms;
      mol1->tipo_coordinate = mol2->tipo_coordinate;
      strcpy(mol1->comment, mol2->comment);
      for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        mol1->v1[i] = mol2->v1[i];
        mol1->v2[i] = mol2->v2[i];
        mol1->v3[i] = mol2->v3[i];
      }
      mol1->scale = mol2->scale;
      mol1->num_symbols = mol2->num_symbols;
      for (i=0; i < mol1->num_symbols; i++) strcpy(&mol1->list_atomi[ i * 3 ], &mol2->list_atomi[ i * 3 ]);
      for (i=0; i < mol2->num_symbols; i++) mol1->num_atomi[i] = mol2->num_atomi[i];
      for (i=0; i < mol2->natoms; i++) {
        mol1->x[i] = mol2->x[i];
        mol1->y[i] = mol2->y[i];
        mol1->z[i] = mol2->z[i];
      }
    }

UPDATE!: UPDATE!: UPDATE!:
For the readers: The code I posted above is correct and the #pragma directives are correct. As suspected I found a very subtle data race bug in one of the many functions that optimize calls. Sorry guys for that, and thanks to everybody for comments. It pushed me to find the solution. I'm sorry I cannot post all the code: it is huge.

A complete program would be in order.

What do functions molcpy and optimize do? Please add code.. Please use default(none) sharing attribute, so you have to define sharing attributes of all of your variables.

I think you should read How does the omp ordered clause work? since there is no ordered region in the loop so I guess you miss-understand how it works.

@Laci: I added molcpy in the text above. optimize function is too complex to be posted, but it modify only the first mol structure. while the other two parameters are not changed.

@Jérôme Richard: to my understanding (which maybe wrong) the ordered clause is used to wait the threads and go back to serial loop. In this case all the matrix could be computed in parallel via the optimize function. So I understood that there is no need for  ordered.

I edited (cleaned) the #pragma omp for, but still the inconsistency remains

@Laci: thank you. However, if I use omp_get_max_threads() before the parallel section it gives 1. I need to know in advance how many threads, to initialize mol_omp[].
Furthermore, even though I have 64 cores, omp_get_num_procs() gives 128, which is much more than I'm going to use in the parallel section. Do you know how to get the proper number of threads before to begin the parallel section? - Thanks -

The 128 is due to SMT. While in many cases you can just divide the number by two to get the number of physical processors, SMT could be disabled in BIOS and Intel seems to be on the way to stop supporting SMT in future processors, so that would not be a very portable solution. Due to these kinds of complexities it is recommended not setting the number of threads in code, but to use the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable, i.e. let the user set it.

@CarloNervi which compiler do you use? Are you sure that omp_get_max_threads() returns 1? Then you should file a bug report. Or did you confuse the function with omp_get_num_threads(), which should actually return 1?

@Joachim My mistake, sorry, I'm new to OpenMP. omp_get_max_threads() works as expected. I'm using gcc Gentoo 13.2.1_p20240113-r1 p12.
I cannot understand how to deal with nested for. The first for should go parallel and initialize the mol_omp[]. The second for loop should retain the same parallelization and use the same mol_omp[].

Is there a reason to not just have a a CRISTALLO declared inside the parallel region such that each thread can initialize its "workspace" in parallel and work on that without any need for omp_get_max_threads() and allocation? Even if that is not a bug, it could cause bad performance due to false sharing. Declaring variables at minimal scope is a good practice, same goes for i and k: If you just decalre them inside the loops (for (int i = 0; i < nmol; ++i)) you don't need to worry about declaring them private in the OMP pragma.

@paleonix I did not think about including CRISTALLO *mol_omp inside the parallel region. I thought that malloc() and free() should be done once outside the parallel sector and not for every thread. In my (little) understanding one malloc() of array should be faster than several ones. Even if mol_omp would be a single variable within the parallel zone, it is in any cases a dynamic array, and I need to malloc() it.

What I'm saying is that if every thread needs just one instance and a single instance is not too big, that instance may well be on the stack. But even when still allocating on the heap, using malloc in the parallel region should be fine.

Do you need to spend all the effort allocating the space for, and copying, the names? It seems unlikely to me that optimize needs them, and you don't use them anywhere in the code you have shown us...

If you suspect a data race, the next time just use ThreadSanitizer with Archer: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/openmp/tools/archer#readme
It's included in LLVM/10+ and icx/2024+

@Joachim Thanks a lot for the link. Even though I'm occasionally a C developer (I'm a chemist), it might be very useful.
